# Pat the Mathemamagician Part 2

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Sal the Magician asks you to pick any five cards from a standard deck. You do so, and
then hand them to Sal’s assistant Pat. Then you pick one of the five cards, and Pat puts
it back into the deck, and takes the remaining 4 cards, arranges them in some way.
Sal is blindfolded, and does not witness any of this. Then Sal takes off the blindfold,
takes the pile of 4 cards, reads the four cards that Pat has arranged, and is able to find
the fifth card in the deck (even if you shuffle the deck after the assistant puts the card
in the deck!). Assume that neither Sal nor Pat have supernatural powers, and that the
deck of cards is not marked, and that the pile of 4 cards that Pat arranges does not have
any funny folding, or weird angles, etc.

How does Sal do this one? This one really has me stumped, maybe I am missing something...

Comment: Martin Gardner describes this trick in *The Unexpected Hanging and Other Mathematical Diversions*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One needs to cheat a bit. There are $48$ missing cards, which can be thought of as $1$ to $48$. (The **meaning** of these numbers depends on the $4$ remaining cards, but Sal knows these.)

Pat and Sal have to encode every integer from $1$ to $48$, using the $4$ cards. There are $24$ permutations of the $4$ cards, not enough. But if Pat is allowed to present the $4$ cards to the magician all faces up or all faces down, there is enough information.

Comment: Nope, you forgot that the assistant can pick which of the five cards to choose, allowing him to effectively reduce the range of the possible missing card.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It's stated in the problem that you pick one of the five cards.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: The wording seemed to indicate that the mark chooses the five cards, **and** chooses the card from the five.

Comment: Ah, the original version of this problem has the assistant choose, in which case my solution is correct, but this variation does not, I see.

Comment: If the assistant were allowed to mix face-up and face-down cards in the arranging of the four remaining cards, then you could do this trick with a deck of 388 cards :)

Comment: Interesting. Still, that would require a *lot* of training or some savant-like skills, unless the magician was allowed to take a few minutes to sort the cards so as to pick the $10011$'th one (and figure out which permutation was shown). ;) But that would sort of kill the impact of the trick...

Comment: I think with a bit of training it would not be hard. Faces up or faces down means we are dealing with missing cards $1$ to $24$ or $25$ to $48$. Sal would *know* the card that the mark had picked, so could announce it without bothering to play with the $48$, that is just for theatre.

Answer (score 0):

"The best card trick" is explained here:

http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring10/cardTrick.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same question, and I am also wondering about the 'harder version' that you have posted.

*By 'harder version' I mean the scenario where the you (the audience) picks the card that is to be returned to the deck. By 'easy version' I mean the scenario where the Pat (the assistant) picks the card to be returned to the deck.*

I did a lot of searching on the internet but I am starting to think it is not possible to do the trick with the 4 cards **alone**, i.e. no additional help such as having the cards face up or down.

Here is a link that I found, which details a method for the 'easy version' for a deck as large as 124 cards. I am wondering if this method can be adapted to do the 'hard version' for 52 cards.

https://web.northeastern.edu/seigen/11Magic/Articles/Best%20Card%20Trick.pdf

Failing that, would there be a way to prove concretely that it is impossible?